# MVVM - Close a window from view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, prism

In my application i'm using prism and trying to implement the following concept:

There is a communication window that can have two possible user controls. I have the ViewModels for the window and the user controlls.
In every user control i have some buttons. For some buttons i need to perform some logic in the ViewModel and when the logic is done, close the parent window.
I tried to send the parant window as a command parameter like this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

And in the viewModel close the window using the following code:

```
// Create the command
OpenChannelCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenChannel, IsValidFields);
...
private void OpenChannel()
{
  // do some logic...
  CloseWindow();
}
private GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object> _closeCommand;
private GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object> CloseWindow()
{
    _closeCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object>((o) => ((Window)o).Close(), (o) => true);
    return _closeCommand;
}
```

But still the window aren't closing.

EDIT:

The user control XAML code is:

```
<Button Content="Open Channel" Command="{Binding OpenChannelCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

The user control ViewModel code is:

```
public RelayCommand OpenChannelCommand { get; set; } 
ctor() 
{
   OpenChannelCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenChannel, IsValidFields);
}     
private void OpenChannel() 
{    
   // logic 
   CloseWindow(); 
}
private GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object> CloseWindow()
{
    _closeCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand<object>((o) => ((Window)o).Close(), (o) => true);
    return _closeCommand;
 }
```

This is the full implementaion that i currently tried.
When setting a breakpoint to the CloseWindow method it hits at the view modet initialization and after calling it again in the button click command is doesn't do a thing.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an event handler to kick off the VM activity, then close the window once it completes?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick response.
I didn't understand your answer. Where should i create the event handler? in the pop up window? 
It won't break the MVVM pattern?

Comment: If you add a breakpoint at `((Window)o).Close()` is it breaking there?

Comment: Typically for things like this I would create an event handler on the button object in XAML, then have it call the method on the VM you want, then close the window. Now, whether or not this breaks the MVVM pattern is up for debate, but I personally think it's less of a 'sin' to have the View know about the View Model than the other way around (which is what you're trying to do here).

Comment: If you link `OpenChannelCommand` to a button than parameter (ref to the window) must be send to this command. You don't need `CloseWindow` to be a command. Just a function with a ptr to a window as a parameter.

Comment: If you want to go full-on MVVM, then a messenger pattern that will allow communication between your VMs and a window manager / window factory might be a good way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the window is the view's responsibility, the view-model should know nothing about it. No wonder you're getting tangled up. If you don't need the window to stay on screen while the "button logic" is running, then just use a `CompositeCommand` from Prism (I don't like it much because it uses code-behind, but no matter) or equivalent to bind two commands to the button. On the other hand, if you need to keep the window on screen while the "button logic" is running, e.g. to display progress, and if your view model reflects this, then you can add a `bool IsButtonLogicComplete` property to your view model (don't forget `INotifyPropertyChanged`) and bind the window's 'closed' state to this property via an attached property/behavior like this one:

```
public static class AttachedProperties
{
    // in Visual Studio, the `propa` snippet inserts the boilerplate
    public static DependencyProperty ForceCloseProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ("ForceClose",
        typeof (bool), typeof (AttachedProperties), new UIPropertyMetadata (false, (d, e) =>
        {
            var w  = d as Window ;
            if (w != null && (bool) e.NewValue)
            {
                w.DialogResult = true ;
                w.Close () ;
            }
        })) ;

    public static bool GetForceClose (DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue (ForceCloseProperty) ;
    }

    public static void SetForceClose (DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue (ForceCloseProperty, value) ;
    }
}

<!-- in .xaml -->
<Window
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
  local:AttachedProperties.ForceClose="{Binding IsButtonLogicComplete}" ...
```

This will keep your view and your view model concerns nicely separated.

Comment: Hi Anton,
I'm trying to implement your approach of using the DependencyProperty but i didn't understand where to implement it. Should i set this method in the Window ViewModel or in the UserControl ViewModel?
Regarding the XAML, who is ForceClose? how the Window should know who it is?

Comment: It's convenient to put attached properties like this one into a public static class somewhere with the view (not viewmodel!) code. [This looks like a good intro](http://www.codemag.com/article/1405061) to attached properties.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve this problem. On top of the one proposed one could also solve it using a framework like MVVM Dialogs or using the mediator in MVVM Light. Regarding whether closing a window is the responsibility of the view model, sure it can be! There is nothing in MVVM that prevents you from opening, nor closing dialogs, as long as you do it in a indirect way that still is testable.

Comment: Sure. With a framework, though, you don't get to learn as much about the basics of WPF.

Comment: Re closing. As I think about it, the window belongs to the view and closing it or keeping it open is entirely the view's business. A different (e.g. mobile) view may initiate a transition rather than close the window, but use the same view model. I am fairly dogmatic about separating view mechanics from view model and this approach works for me; YMMV. As for opening dialogs from the view model, I can see that for modal dialogs that must ask the user for urgently required information (e.g. credentials) but as you say such services are usually injected without direct reference to view stuff.